# Setting GCP in OpenDroneMap Project

Tags: ground-control, opendronemap

I have run OpenDroneMap(ODM) on a bunch of drone images of a particular area. I have set the Ground Control Points(GCP) using Webodm gcp interface. Now, I have a gcp_list.txt file containing the images with appropriate latitude, longitude values. Now, in the OpenDroneMap Documentaion, it is stated that:

**The gcp_list.txt file must be created in the base of your project folder.**

Now, I have run ODM keeping the gcp_list.txt file in the images folder. But, I am not clear about where I should put the gcp_list.txt file exactly.

What does this actually mean?

What is the base of my project folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you set your project to hold images in
`/exam/ple/project/images` then it's the `/exam/ple/project` (just one level up, this directory does not need to be called project) that you should put `gcp_list.txt` in. You can also specify other location and/or name for this file by providing it with `--gcp <path>`